# mysql doesn't stop on mac os x

Tags: mysql, macos, mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql doesn't stop on mac os x](https://superuser.com/questions/221954/mysql-doesnt-stop-on-mac-os-x)

Hi there,

I have mysql installed on 10.6 Snow Leopard. The problem is that I cant stop the server. Its running all the time.

How can I solve that? I tried to install mysql again, but this didn't solve the problem. How about deinstalling the server? I read that I should turn the server of before deinstalling it, but that is exactly what I can't do...

Hints?

Comment: You probably should ask on http://superuser.com

Comment: what's the difference between stackoverflow and superuser?

Comment: One's for programming questions. The other is for superuser questions.